# Add a new row in datagrid and add values to the columns in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to add a new row to a data grid and add values to the columns.
I am pretty new to WPF and not able to figure out how to do it. I tried a few ways but all are throwing errors.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Background="DarkGray"
      CanUserResizeColumns="True"
       CanUserSortColumns="True" 
       x:Name="ManifestFile"
       AutoGenerateColumns="False"
       ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DatFileName}"
                            Header="File Name"
                            MinWidth="100"
                            FontFamily="Default Font"
                            FontSize="16" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AcquiredTime}"
                            Header="Total Time"
                            MinWidth="100"
                            FontFamily="Default Font"
                            FontSize="16" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NumPacketsInFile}"
                            Header="Total Packet"
                            MinWidth="100"
                            FontFamily="Default Font"
                            FontSize="16" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

XAML.cs-- I have to do something like this. I have values but don't know how to put that in the columns after creating the row.

```
for (int i = 0; i < p_aSortedFiles[l_sKey].Count; i++)
    {
            //need to add a row 
        ManifestFile.Items.Add(new Item());  // throwing error
        first column = p_aSortedFiles[l_sKey][i];
            second column =23;
        third column = 22;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give an example.